# View model com ICollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou iniciando no desenvolvimento mobile e estou fazendo um sisteminha de controle de categorias. Onde dou possibilidade de fazer vários níveis de categorias.

Minha entidade ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
public string Descricao { get; set; }
public int? CategoriaPaiId { get; set; }
public virtual Categoria CategoriaPai { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Categoria> CategoriasFilho { get; set; }
```

A minha duvida está sendo ao criar minhas `ViewModel`

Comecei a programar e até o momento está assim:

```
    [Key]
    public int CategoriaId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Categoria pai")]
    public string CategoriaPaiId { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Descrição da categoria")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Descrição obrigatória.")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Ativo")]
    public bool Status { get; set; }
```

Como posso concluir isto ?

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta. Por que você precisa criar uma `ViewModel`?

Comment: Porque aqui utilizo a viewmodel para instanciar meu objeto

Comment: Sim, mas por que? Qual o objetivo disso? A `ViewModel` é quase idêntica ao `Model`. Não há necessidade disso se elas forem iguais, ou quase iguais.

Comment: Não sei a explicação correta, como disse sou novo, no projeto padrão a qual estou seguinte ele tem duas view model, que chama CategoriaViewModel e GerenciarCategoriaViewModel, nela estão os dados descritos de minha entidade, preciso descrever nela um lista, de categorias

Comment: Bom, este padrão é prolixo e acredito que você possa simplificar. Vou direcionar uma resposta sem considerar `ViewModels`, ok?

Comment: ok @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A separação em *ViewModels* só é necessária se a exposição de dados em apresentação (*Views*) for diferente do que é proposto em *Model*. Ou seja, se o seu *Model* está assim:

```
public int CategoriaId { get; set; }
public string Descricao { get; set; }
public int? CategoriaPaiId { get; set; }
public virtual Categoria CategoriaPai { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Categoria> CategoriasFilho { get; set; }
```

Você só precisa decorá-lo como fez com seu *ViewModel*, e isto ainda pode ser melhorado:

```
[Key]
public int CategoriaId { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Categoria pai")]
public int? CategoriaPaiId { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Descrição da categoria")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Descrição obrigatória.")]
public string Descricao { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Ativo")]
public bool Status { get; set; }

public virtual Categoria CategoriaPai { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Categoria> CategoriasFilho { get; set; }
```

Não tem problema expor um *Model* em *View*. Para proteger quais campos podem ser definidos, utilize o atributo [`[Bind]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) com `Include`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Criar([Bind(Include = "Descricao,CategoriaPaiId")] Categoria categoria) { ... }
```

Ou, se for mais fácil, `Exclude`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Criar([Bind(Exclude = "CategoriaId,CategoriaPai,CategoriasFilho")] Categoria categoria) { ... }
```